# How does the mob grinder work?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

There is a [tutorial describing how to build a mob farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VZgA8Kp8b0M). It uses following pattern:

```
S = Stone (or other solid opaque block)
W = water 2 levels under the stone
H = hole
B = border wall

|--------------20 blocks--------------|
B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B W W W W W W W W H H W W W W W W W W B
B W W W W W W W W H H W W W W W W W W B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B S S S S S S S S W W S S S S S S S S B
B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B B
```

When the farm was built, mobs started to fall out immediatelly. This is a little suprising. If they appear on the stone platforms, shouldn't they just wander and only randomly fall in the water streams? How come they fall in so frequently? Do they walk there on purpose?

Comment: First, this is a horrible design for a mob farm.  Second, are you referring to the rate shown in the video?  Because it looks to me like it's sped up.

Comment: Might be sped up, but really not significantly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question, the mobs DO NOT fall into the water on purpose and it is random when they fall into the water. If you are talking about why they fell so frequently in the video, the following reasons exists:

- The mob farm is extra large
- The video was sped up

I am more certain of the latter reason as in the video, the sun was moving abnormally fast across the screen. While it is true that a natural mob farm of such a size is very unlikely to produce mobs that fast, a larger mob farm could.

In conclusion, the mobs **DO fall randomly into the water**. They **DO NOT fall in on purpose**. The **video might have been sped up**, allowing it to appear as if the mobs spawned and fell to their deaths so frequently.

Comment: I just tested it - if the farm is the only viable spawning points, the mobs really fall out quite often.